# Nested apply function at a list

Tags: functional-style

Given a function `f` and a list `{a,b,c,d,e}` how can I compactly tell mathematica to return `f[a,f[b,f[c,f[d,e]]]]`?

It seems that `Apply` can do the job but I cannot make it work as I want.

Comment: What you want to do is best expressed by a `Fold` operation i.e. `Fold[f,list]`. Check out the documentation, it should be quite straightforward. If you need help you can ask again.

Comment: Ah, yes! I knew that there should be a way, I didn't know how it was called. Thanks!

Comment: @AndreasP It's not that straightforward: `Fold[f, Reverse@{a, b, c, d, e}]` gives `f[f[f[f[e, d], c], b], a]`, while the OP wants the arguments of every `f` to be in reversed order.

Comment: No worries, in my case the arguments of f commute. Through work.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @corey979, I didn't look at the question that closely, my bad.
For completions sake, this'd work: `Fold[f[#2, #1] &, Reverse@{a, b, c, d, e}]`

Comment: A useful guide is [`Functional Iteration`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FunctionalIteration.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function you want to use is `Fold` which does almost what you want to do i.e.

```
Fold[f,{a,b,c}]
Out[] := f[f[f[a, b], c], d]
```

Above operation is called `FoldRight` in other other languages, because it *folds* the function from left to the right over the list of arguments. 
Your question asks for a `FoldLeft` which you can easily implement by

1. Reversing the inputlist
2. Reversing the argument-order of `f`

The former can be achieved by a simple `Reverse` on the list, the latter by switching the arguments to the function `f` by defining an anonymous function `f[#2,#1]&`.

Thus you get your result with

```
Fold[f[#2, #1] &, Reverse@{a, b, c, d, e}]
Out[]:= f[a, f[b, f[c, f[d, e]]]]
```

Comment: An explicit definition for foldLeft:
`foldLeft[func_,x_,list_]:=Fold[func[#2, #1] &,x, Reverse@list]`